# Ignoring part of a key dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

I want to have a dictionary in which the keys are tuples such as (1, 0). However, I want all keys of the form (n, 0) to identify with a similar output, and it'd be nice if I didn't have to have all the tuples from (1, 0) to (n, 0) as keys in my dictionary. Is there a simple way I can do this?

```
dictionary = {(n, 1): [n, 3], (n, 2): [5, n], (n, 0): [0, n]}
```

Comment: rebuild your dict with "n" as key and a list of values instead?

Comment: Are you trying to make all the `(n, 0)` keys share a single value, or are you trying to make any `(n, 0)` key map to `[0, n]` without storing an infinite number of items?

Comment: I want them all to map to `[0, n]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a dict with a special rule for handling keys that aren't actually stored in the dict hash table, you want to create a subclass of `dict` that implements [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__):

> Called by `dict.__getitem__()` to implement `self[key]` for `dict` subclasses when key is not in the dictionary.

Like this:

```
class SpecialDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple) and len(key) == 2 and key[1] == 0:
            return [0, key]
        raise KeyError(key)
```

I don't really understand how your example is supposed to work, so here's a different example to demonstrate it:

```
>>> d = SpecialDict({(1, 1): [2, 3], (1, 2): [5, 4]})
>>> d[1, 1]
[2, 3]
>>> d[2, 2]
KeyError: (2, 2)
>>> d[20, 0]
[0, 20]
```

If you store a value for a `(n, 0)` key, it won't call `__missing__` for that key, allowing you to override a single `(n, 0)` while leaving the rest with their special rule:

```
>>> d[42, 0] = [23, 23]
>>> d[42, 0]
[23, 23]
>>> d[23, 0]
[0, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the value (1,0) to (n,0) and then delete the element (1,0) from dict. Like these:

```
dictionary[n,0] = dictionary[1,0]
del dictionary[1,0]
```

and so on, But for identifying for similar output you have to make the value into tuple by using set() and then take the difference with the key. Like these:

```
 for key in dictionary:
    if set(key) - set(dictionary[key]) is set():
       print("Similar key value pair")
```